# Running custom Java functions within XSLT and SAXON (9.1.8)

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, xslt, saxon

**Meta**

- Saxon XSLT processor (v. 9.1.8)
- Java
- XSLT 2.0

I got a simple example of a java class file and some xsl transformation. My goal is to run my custom java functions from the class file within the XSLT process (via SAXON). *How is this possible?* When I start the below described batch file the cmd displays an error calling me the function is not known to saxon. So I have to add my class to the Java / or Saxon CLASSPATH?

The transformation should copy all XML data and (return &) display the dimension of imagefiles.

**My XSL Transformation**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ImageInfo="java:ImageInfo"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
<xsl:template/>

<xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:copy>
        [image] file found: <xsl:value-of select="ImageInfo:getImageWidth(@src)"/> x <xsl:value-of select="ImageInfo:getImageHeight(@src)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Java Class**

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class ImageInfo {

String filename;
ImageIcon img;

public ImageInfo(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    img = new ImageIcon(filename);
}

public int getWidth() {
    return img.getIconWidth();
}

public int getHeight() {
    return img.getIconHeight();
}
}
```

**Saxon command line call (via .BAT)**

```
java -jar "%~dp0\saxonb9-1-0-8j\saxon9.jar" -s:"data.xml" -xsl:"transformation.xsl" -o:"result.xml"
```

Comment: I understand that this question is old, but I still will be hoping for answer - where I need to put custom java extension classes so that xsl can find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `-cp` option of your `java` command e.g. `java -cp ".;%~dp0\saxonb9-1-0-8j\saxon9.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:"data.xml" -xsl:"transformation.xsl" -o:"result.xml"` where you need to make sure that the directory with your `ImageInfo` is on the class path, I have added `.`, assuming the class is in your current working directory.

However, note that `ImageInfo:getImageWidth(@src)` would try to call a static method `getImageWidth`, you have instance methods, the method you have is called `getWidth` and it does not take an argument.

See the documentation for that old version of Saxon 9, it should be available on http://saxon.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: extending the classpath and adding the main class from saxon helped. thanks.

Comment: Note that classpath separator will is OS-dependent - on Unix it's `:`

Answer (score 1):

Once you've sorted out your classpath problems as Martin suggests, the code you want will be something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="image" select="ImageInfo:new(@src)"/>
[image] file found: 
   <xsl:value-of select="ImageInfo:getWidth($image)"/> x 
   <xsl:value-of select="ImageInfo:getHeight($image)"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much. is it neccessary to create a new java object in order to call the functions?

Comment: The methods getWidth() and getHeight() are methods defined on an instance of a class, so yes, you can't call them without having an instance to apply them to.

Comment: I see. So I´ve decided to create the object within the returning type methods themselves and let them take the input parameter from the methods. Works fine now. again - thanks for your help!