# Using XSLT to get image metadata

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I have XML which contains links to various image files which looks something like this:

```
<xml>
   <image>
      <name>fig1.jpg</name>
      <type>graphic</type>
      <path>C:\some folder\artwork\fig1.jpg</path>
   </image>
   <image>
      <name>fig2.jpg</name>
      <type>graphic</type>
      <path>C:\some folder\artwork\fig2.jpg</path>
   </image>
</xml>
```

Is it possible to process this using XSLT to get various metadata on these images, such as resolution, width, height, and file format? So basically something I can pass the path to, and it will return the data I want.

I have been looking around for an answer and it seems like some kind of java extension function is what I am looking for, but I have no knowledge of java so can't really grasp what I need to do or how to make it work.

There are some java functions such as for formatting dates where I have seen examples in use and they seem no more difficult to get working that standard XSLT functions, but then I suppose these are essentially processing text rather than an external image files so is that where I am coming unstuck?

I think the closest thing I have found to what I need to do is this: [Running custom Java functions within XSLT and SAXON (9.1.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150099/running-custom-java-functions-within-xslt-and-saxon-9-1-8)

However, I can't seem to make it work for me. I am trying this to add a `<size>` element to the original XML, so this seemed logical to me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ImageInfo="java:ImageInfo"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="path">

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>

        <size>
            <xsl:variable name="image" select="ImageInfo:new(.)"/>
            [image] file found: 
            <xsl:value-of select="ImageInfo:getWidth($image)"/> x 
            <xsl:value-of select="ImageInfo:getHeight($image)"/>
        </size>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Oxygen is giving me these error messages:

```
Stylesheet compilation failed: 3 errors reported
XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 15 in {ImageInfo:new(.)}: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {java:ImageInfo}new(). For diagnostics on calls to Java methods, use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS
XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 17 in {ImageInfo:getWidth($image)}: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {java:ImageInfo}getWidth(). For diagnostics on calls to Java methods, use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS
XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 18 in {ImageInfo:getHeight($image)}: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {java:ImageInfo}getHeight(). For diagnostics on calls to Java methods, use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS
```

I am using Saxon EE in Oxygen 17.1, if that helps.

Any help or any pointers to a resource that is suitable for someone who is comfortable with XSLT, but is a total java novice, would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the ImageInfo class is obviously part of the issue, perhaps you should edit your question and include the code for that class.

Comment: From where you get image size, if it is not a part of xml? Where is your java code?

Comment: Is it this ImageInfo class that you are trying to use? http://kickjava.com/src/imageinfo/ImageInfo.java.htm

Comment: Thanks for replying. Since I don't really understand your queries, it suggests to me that I need to go back to basics as I don't know what I am doing here. I have never before even tried to use java so am totally lost. Perhaps this isn't a simple thing to do as I hoped? Is what I am trying even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think your first problem is probably that you haven't found the documentation. You're trying to do this just by copying code that you don't understand from another StackOverflow posting, and copying code that you don't understand and modifying it to do something slightly different is never a very effective strategy.

I guess that the ImageInfo class you want to use is probably

org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageInfo

but I'm not familiar with that class and can't tell you how to use it without doing some research. I've done enough research to establish that it's documented here:

```
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/
```

and this gives some examples, for example how to extract metadata of an image. I'm afraid these example are all Java code, but you're unlikely to find anything else. They do show you the sequence of calls needed.

The Saxon documentation for how to call Java methods is here:
    http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/functions

You will need to make sure:

(a) that you have downloaded and installed any Java library you are calling

(b) that the JAR files for this library are on the classpath when you invoke Saxon

(c) that you use the full class name as a namespace when calling functions, for example

```
xmlns:ImageInfo="java:org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageInfo"
```

I'm sorry that if you have no Java experience, this is going to be a bit daunting.

Comment: Thank you for that reply! You are absolutely right; unfortunately I am in a situation where there is a problem to solve but a lack of time to properly learn something new to do it. I am very aware I am going in too high and too quick. However, that information should help me and I am grateful for it.